# Sqlalchemy Query - How to get two columns

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

How can I make a query like this in sqlalchemy:

```
select users.user_id, cpf, name , email,cpf,candidate.candidate_id  ,university as "universidade", course as "curso",linkedin, github, school_records, university_registration as "matricula", lattes, softs_skills,curriculum from users, candidate where candidate.user_id = users.user_id ;
```

I already tried that way, but I get the error of: too many values ​​to unpack

```
columns = [
            User.user_id,
            User.cpf,
            User.name,
            User.email,
            Candidate.candidate_id,
            Candidate.university.label('universidade'),
            Candidate.course.label('curso'),
            Candidate.linkedin,
            Candidate.github,
            Candidate.school_records,
            Candidate.university_registration.label('matricula'),
            Candidate.lattes
            Candidate.softs_skills,
            Candidate.curriculum
           ]
            UsersCandidate = []
            async with self.db as session:
                    stmt = select(*columns).select_from(Candidate, User).where(Candidate.user_id == User.user_id)
                    exec = await session.execute(stmt)
                    results = exec.scalars().fetchall()
                    for row in results:
                        user_id, cpf, name, email, candidate_id, universidade, curso, linkedin, github, school_records, matricula, lattes, softs_skills, curriculum = row
                        item = {
                        'user_id': user_id,
                        'cpf': cpf,
                        'name': name,
                        'email': email,
                        'candidate_id': candidate_id,
                        'universidade': universidade,
                        'curso': curso,
                        'linkedin': linkedin,
                        'github': github,
                        'school_records': school_records,
                        'matricula': matricula,
                        'lattes': lattes,
                        'softs_skills': softs_skills,
                        'curriculum': curriculum
                    }
                        UsersCandidate.append(item)
                        session.close()
    
             return UsersCandidate
```

Or else, is there any way to run native sql with sqlalchemy?

Comment: Yes, you can do `session.execute("select <cols> from table (...)")`Actually your example seems fine and should work. Please specify exactly where the error occured and try to produce minimal, reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I solved removing the scalars. Honestly, I don't know what it's for.

Comment: `scalars()` is just a shortcut.  If you just fetched one column (or one object), like `select(User.user_id)` then you could use `scalars()` to prevent needing to unpack each row, like `for user_id in results` instead of `for (user_id,) in results` or in your example instead of `(user_id,) = row`.  It usually doesn't make sense to use it when you query for multiple columns or objects.